# WPF style basedon current

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Is there a way to create a style that extends the current style, i.e. not a specific style?

I have a WPF application where I create styles to set some properties like borders or validation.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"  
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,2,5,2"/>
    </Style>
```

Now I want to try out some Themes to see which one works best for my application. Problem is that to do that I need to change the BasedOn property on all my Styles to the style in the Theme.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"  
           BasedOn="="{x:Static ns:SomeTheme.ButtonStyle}">">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,2,5,2"/>
    </Style>
```

I can do it via search/replace but it would be nice if it could be done dynamicly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do it in this way only, there is no shortcut to do this, you have to set BasedOn attribute atleast.

Answer (score 1):

if you store all your resources in seperate assemblies from your ui then you can use themes to dynamically change them at runtime.

[themes in seperate assembly](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Themes.html)

[loading different themes at runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfdynamicthemes.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource`.

Comment: Error message: "Property 'BasedOn' does not support values of type 'DynamicResourceExtension'."